# I need non stop clock counter which will even not stop on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: Counter clock]

I make this counter clock but it resets when I load the page, saved in my computer.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var clock;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var clock;

        clock = $('.clock').FlipClock({
            clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
            autoStart: false,
            callbacks: {
                stop: function() {
                    $('.message').html('The clock has stopped!')
                }
            }
        });

        clock.setTime(220880);
        clock.setCountdown(true);
        clock.start();

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Seems like you're missing something. What is ```FlipClock```. A library? You should add it as a tag/link to the lib to your post.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a page is readloaded, the entire context of the old page is destroyed and an entirely new context is created. You can't keep a timer from one page load running on the next page load.

If you need to save some state from one page load to the next and then in the next page load examine that state and decide exactly how to set up the initial page to match what was previously going on, then you can save state between page loads in either HTML5 local storage or in a cookie.

The other possibility is to NOT reload your page and instead update the contents of the page dynamically using ajax and javascript. That way your existing timer would just keep running because there would be no page reload at all.

If all you're trying to do with your timer is show how much time is left in some countdown, you can set the countdown zero time into HTML5 local storage and when the reloaded page loads, it can check the time set in local storage and start the countdown timer to match the time it was previously set for.